# How do I install libtool-bin on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I was able to install libtool on my Ubuntu 14.04 box with trouble using apt-get, but I also need libtool-bin and apt-get can't find it.  I have both the main and universe lists installed.  How do I install libtool-bin?

Comment: Why do you need it? In 14.04, the `libtool` binary is in the `libtool` package, and the `libtool-bin` package from new releases doesn't contain much else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need `libtool-bin` package on trusty, just install `libtool` packages.

You can compare package contents of [`libtool` in trusty](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libtool/filelist) with [`libtool-bin` in xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libtool/filelist) - both have `/usr/bin/libtool`.

For sure do not forget to install `build-essential` package for successful compilation.